# Keyboard's buttons

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, function-keys

I have Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and my keyboard is: Genius SlimStar i222.
I have problem about Fn(function key). To exlain my problem:
When i press buttons Fn and F1 at the same time, ubuntu opens home folder instead my web browser. Is it possible to make my keyborad to do appropriate things?
thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have that keyboard, but if you go to System Settings > Keyboards > the Shorcut tab (as shown below), you can configure what the "Explorer" (I think that's how that key is called) do:

[image]

Just click over the "Launch web browser", press the key combination and done.